# How do I add initial value to empty string?

Tags: swift

I want to see if a string is empty, and if so, insert the number "1".
how do i do this in swift 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps something like this:

```
var example = String()
if example.isEmpty {
    example = "1"
}
```

For some further reading about the basic empty string syntax in swift i'd recommend: https://www.dotnetperls.com/isempty-swift

Comment: @AndyIbanez I am surprised i have enough brain to power on my computer.